# Remove Toshiba laptop BIOS password?

Tags: bios, passwords, toshiba-laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bypass BIOS password set by faulty Toshiba firmware on Satellite A55-S1065 laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/243413/bypass-bios-password-set-by-faulty-toshiba-firmware-on-satellite-a55-s1065-lapto)

I have a Toshiba Satellite l500 laptop, when I power it on, it shows a black screen and asks for the BIOS password.

It is neither going to the BIOS or booting up...

I do not know this password, nor how to remove it.  What do I do?

Comment: Where did you get the laptop?

Comment: In some cases a replacement motherboard is needed.  Contact Toshiba or the folks that sold it to you.

Comment: why a down vote?

Comment: Did you try asking the person who SET the password?

Answer (score 1):

If it is an Admin password, cmos reset will not work, only works for power on passwords.

If an admin password has been set you will need to send it off to be reset.

Some say [this](http://www.cgsecurity.org/keydisk.exe) utility will reset bios passwords on older Toshiba laptops

.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/CmosPwd

Comment: I think I have read somewhere that Toshiba laptops does not store passwords in the battery-backed RAM in the cmos chip, so if you pull the battery you will only loose all the BIOS settings but not the password.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a laptop's BIOS can be reset in the same way you would with a regular PC: by temporarily removing both the main and CMOS batteries. How hard it is to find the CMOS battery depends entirely on the model of you laptop.

You may find a manual for your laptop here:
http://cdgenp01.csd.toshiba.com/content/support/manuals/userguides/su2342557/GMAD00201012_SatL500_Rev_09Jun10.pdf
In my brief scan of the manual i found that it may be necessary to leave the laptop turned off for an extended period of time (read "1 month+"). Even then it appears to be a long shot.

Good luck.