# Removing BIOS password from Toshiba laptop

Tags: bios, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bypass BIOS password set by faulty Toshiba firmware on Satellite A55-S1065 laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/243413/bypass-bios-password-set-by-faulty-toshiba-firmware-on-satellite-a55-s1065-lapto)

How can I remove the BIOS password from a Toshiba Satellite Pro A300-10p, Model No. PSAG9E-00y001EN?

Comment: http://www.edugeek.net/forums/hardware/29249-toshiba-satellite-pro-bios-pwd.html

Comment: There probably is an internal jumper that can be set, then power on the machine.  (Or look for the "W-shaped" tab under the memory.)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, all BIOS settings, including the password, can be reset by removing the CMOS battery. On a laptop, this is not a trivial task, as it often includes taking out a lot of components. Luckily, there are plenty of guides out there to help you disassemble the machine, but according to [this one](http://www.irisvista.com/tech/laptops/Toshiba-Satellite-A305/laptop-disassembly-process-1.htm), the battery is soldered onto the motherboard. You can do some soldering of your own to get it off, or drain its energy, but I don't see any switches or jumpers to reset the BIOS easily.

Comment: Thank you dear, actually the password is Non-Volatile memory not in volatile memory. Any one can remove the password from Volatile memory by removing the CMOS battery but the BIOS password can not be removed from EEPROM. There should be some other method to remove it, please findout and advice.