# What do I now I forgot the Toshiba Satellite S55T-A5360 BIOS password?

Tags: windows-8, bios, passwords, satellite

I have Toshiba Satellite S55T-A5360 Laptop. I forget the BIOS password. What can I do? I did not find the jumper or how I can change the password.

Comment: [Bypass BIOS password set by faulty Toshiba firmware on Satellite A55-S1065 laptop?](http://superuser.com/a/250168)

Comment: enter the wrong password 3 or more times, you should now get a code, write it down and post it, there may be a password generator to make a master password to unlock it.

Answer (score 0):

Really sorry but in my experience the only way to resolve this is to contact the manufacturer or Manually remove the CMOS battery (this is **not** recommended).

There is also some software about on the net which can help but personally I would contact the manufacturer and see if they can help before trying anything else.

Here is a link to a page with some workarounds for locked BIOS. I must stress please only do this if you can't get the information you need from the manufacturer. https://www.technibble.com/how-to-bypass-or-remove-a-bios-password/

Answer (score 0):

On modern laptops, bios password is stored in EEPROM which keeps its content after power loss.

There is no easy/software method for a user to remove the password. if you still have warranty(and proper receipt) maybe you can try manufacturer warranty process, otherwise, find a laptop repair shop, they have proper utility to read the EEPROM and get the password if its not encrypted, or maybe just desoldering/resolder a new EEPROM chip.