# Toshiba Satellite C655-S5225 bios reset/remove

Tags: bios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bypass BIOS password set by faulty Toshiba firmware on Satellite A55-S1065 laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/243413/bypass-bios-password-set-by-faulty-toshiba-firmware-on-satellite-a55-s1065-lapto)

I am helping my cousin, with getting her laptop backup and running and it appears her daughter for some reason or another set the bios password but has forgotten it.  I have read online about shorting out certain jumpers but nothing that pertains to this particular model (Toshiba Satellite C655-s5225).  Any information or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Bypass BIOS password set by faulty Toshiba firmware on Satellite A55-S1065 laptop?](http://superuser.com/q/243413)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bypass BIOS password set by faulty Toshiba firmware on Satellite A55-S1065 laptop?](http://superuser.com/questions/243413/bypass-bios-password-set-by-faulty-toshiba-firmware-on-satellite-a55-s1065-lapto) and/or [Remove Toshiba laptop BIOS password?](http://superuser.com/questions/215385/remove-toshiba-laptop-bios-password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either short the pins or remove the CMOS battery. You have to be really careful when performing a laptop disassembly, especially with the tape like cables.  The following is a step by step tutorial for the Toshiba Satellite C655:

http://www.irisvista.com/tech/laptops/Toshiba-Satellite-C650-C655/disassemble-toshiba-laptop-1.htm

Check step 22, to get a better view make sure to click on picture.