# Startup password on toshiba laptop

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, passwords

My system is stuck on "Enter startup password" screen.When i try some password it goes to automatic startup repair.If i go into bios to change or delete startup password,what i see there is 
user : registered
supervisor : registered 
When i try to change password it does not accept the new password.
I have access to windows 8 advanced options.
If i try to reset it ask for disk.
If i try to restore or refresh option on computer it tells me to login through admin account.

Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Toshiba laptop BIOS password?](http://superuser.com/questions/215385/remove-toshiba-laptop-bios-password)

Comment: If it is a bios password, how did you get past the bios to the advanced screen?

Comment: I try a password ryan1962 and it takes me to automatic repair screen.I am not aware of what kind of password is it.